# Autokey RTL input for other than MsgBox?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to output Arabic text, which is RTL orientated on an output window. This output window is to serve as a scrolling window of your history, one snippet at a time. MsgBox has the RTL parameter, but is unfriendly when it comes to handling the scrolling function. The scrolling function should work by merely scrolling the middle mouse button, so you can scroll quickly through 50 history snippets, one by one.

Comment: Could you be clearer in your question? Do you have any code to start out with?

Comment: The question is about RTL text output to something, whatever that may be. MsgBox has that function, but it gives me other disadvantages. Either an alternative is required, or either a workaround of those disadvantages. The main function that needs to remain preserved is the capability to refresh the output window with NEW output from my history by scrolling the middle mouse button for instance. MsgBox is not going to allow me to do that without me having to click an ok button the whole time or waiting for a timer to pass. Or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example:

```
myPid := DllCall("GetCurrentProcessId")
wordList := "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur"
StringSplit, wordList, wordList, %A_SPACE%
counter := 0
myMsgBox := -1

F9::
    myMsgBox := WinExist("ahk_pid " myPid " ahk_class #32770")
    if(counter + 1 > wordList0) {
        ControlSetText, Static1, DONE
        return
    }
    counter++
    if(!myMsgBox) {
        SetTimer, MakeMyMsgBox, -1
    } else {
        ControlSetText, Static1, % wordList%counter%
    }
return

MakeMyMsgBox:
    MsgBox, 1048576, RTL Test, % wordList%counter%
return
```

The salient point is the use of `SetTimer` to produce the `MsgBox`, allowing the hotkey routine to run again although there's a waiting MsgBox window present. Instead of closing the old MsgBox and producing a new one every time, I update the existing one with `ControlSetText`.

Comment: Why does MsgBox only render the title in RTL? The text inside the MsgBox is LTR.